# Make Jquery function wait for previous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a feed that loads every five seconds. I've got the first part to work where it loads while you're just sitting on the site. My next issue now is that it just pops up suddenly, so I'm trying to get it to look smoother.

```
function FinalizeFeed(result) {
    $(".useractivity").html(result);
}
function LoadFeedData() {
    var dataString = "action=loaduserfeed";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/core/functions.d/feed.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $(".post-loading").html('<center><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>').fadeOut("slow");
            setTimeout(FinalizeFeed(result), 2000);
        }

    });
}
```

So my thought was create the `FinalizeFeed` function. Works fine, but still just pops up. If I don't add the Finalize function under the `.post-loading.html` the spinner shows up and looks real nice, but doesn't really help with loading new data in. with the setTimeout I thought it would wait, but the spinner doesn't even show up. Does anyone see what the issue is with this code?

Comment: Try adding the spinner to `beforeSend: function() { // spinner code here }` then *wipe* it *post* `success` function, ie. after the timeout or in the `complete: function() {}`

Comment: And creating a function (`FinalizeFeed()`) is pointless, really. `setTimeout(function() {
  $(".useractivity").html(result);
}, 2000);` would suffice just fine. Functions are meant for re-usability purposes. This appears to be a *one-off* case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delay the `result` response. Even by 2 seconds. You don't actually *want* spinners and loaders showing, as that indicates slow-loading data. If `/core/functions.d/feed.php` fires and sends a response in 100ms, why wait an additional 1900ms to display it?

By adding your spinner/loader to `beforeSend`, the spinner fires on the initial `$.ajax()` call, and is removed once the operation is complete.

So in removing the `setTimeout()` the data is returned, and displayed, once it is available. Once the operation is `complete`, the spinner is removed.

Aside: All to often I see people delaying responses just to have a flashy spinner showing. Users want data, not spinners.

```
function LoadFeedData() {
    var dataString = "action=loaduserfeed";
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".post-loading").html('<center><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/core/functions.d/feed.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $(".useractivity").html(result);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".post-loading").html('');
        }
    });
}
```

By removing `FinalizeFeed()` you're now streamlining your code. That function is tightly *coupled* into your `$.ajax()` success function, so it's not actually reusable, and therefore, not worth creating.

Comment: Thank you. Better way to run it and my data looks cleaner as it updates.

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(FinalizeFeed(result), 2000);
```

This calls `FinalizeFeed(result)` then passes the results of that function call to `setTimeout`.

You want this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    FinalizeFeed(result)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Well; still not displaying the spinner at all, so not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
 function FinalizeFeed(result) {
   $(".useractivity").html(result);
 }

 function LoadFeedData() {
   var dataString = "action=loaduserfeed";
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/core/functions.d/feed.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     beforeSend: function() {
      $(".post-loading").html('<center><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>');
     },
     success: function(result) {
       $(".post-loading").fadeOut("slow");
       setTimeout(function(){
         FinalizeFeed(result)
       }, 2000);
     }

   });
 }
```

So before sending you show the spinner, then on success you hide the spinner and call the function with setTimeout.

Otherwise on your code you are showing the spinner on success and fading it out, so if the request takes long it wont show up until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Move fadeOut inside finalizeFeed() and wrap your timeout code with an anonymous function for it to be executed later.

```
 function FinalizeFeed(result) {
$(".post-loading").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".useractivity").html(result);
  }
  function LoadFeedData() {
  var dataString = "action=loaduserfeed";
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/core/functions.d/feed.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $(".post-loading").html('<center><i class="fa fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>');
                setTimeout(function (){FinalizeFeed(result)}, 2000);
            }

            });
   }
```

Comment: You need to fix the call to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update data every 5 seconds. You can do it like this:

```
//function FinalizeFeed(result) { //no need
//    $(".useractivity").html(result);
//}
function LoadFeedData() {
    $(".useractivity").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".post-loading")
        .html('<center><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></center>')
        .fadeIn("slow");
    var dataString = "action=loaduserfeed";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/core/functions.d/feed.php",
        data: dataString,
        //cache: false, //this is redundant. post request never cache
        success: function(result){
            $(".useractivity").html(result).fadeIn("slow");
            $(".post-loading").fadeOut("slow");
            //setTimeout(FinalizeFeed(result), 2000);//no need; bad syntax
            //"FinalizeFeed(result)" or function(){FinalizeFeed(result);} expected
            //New cycle starts after 5 sec after data received. 
            //Response time is unpredictable.
            setTimeout(LoadFeedData, 5000); 
        }

    });
}
```